# maven-resources-plugin set to different phase

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to force `maven-resources-plugin` execution for different phase like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            ...
```

I see in logs this `plugin` is executed first, before my `maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources)
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
```

Why is this the case?
(I based above on this docu: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)

---

I still don't get it. I will describe root cause of my problem. I have this tasks:

1. `maven-war-plugin` generates me WAR file (@ phase `<phase>compile</phase>`)
2. `maven-resources-plugin` *I want to force execution here*
3. `checksum-maven-plugin` generates for me a checksum file (@ phase `<phase>package</phase>`).

Normally I can't do that because form my observation `maven-resources-plugin` is executed before my war is created. I though I will put this plugin to `test` phase. But what are your suggestions? What phase will be good for that? How to do that?

---

Underlying problem description. I want to provide two files as application:

- WAR file.
- JAR for deployment which validates WAR file by checksum before deployment.

Comment: regarding your edit, as I've specified in my answer, there is no such thing as "forcing a plugin". A given **goal** from a given **plugin** (of which can be **more than one** per plugin) can be executed **multiple times within the build, each with an independent configuration**. An example of a goal is `maven-resources-plugin:resources`, which means the `resources` **goal** from the `maven-resources-plugin` **plugin**. And like I said, rearranging the default might mess up your build. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have two target files created by Maven. One is WAR and one is JAR which deploys the WAR. I try to add some checksum file to the JAR file to later at execution validate the WAR.

Comment: is the `WAR` to be included in the `JAR`?

Comment: `maven-war-plugin` generates me WAR in `target` dir. Not sure how to add this to JAR. Could solve my problem (I would skip checksum calculation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there's another execution for [a goal for this plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins) defined by a parent POM or lifecycle specification.

Check `mvn help:effective-pom` in your project's directory and you'll see how your POM actually looks like.

It sounds like you're assuming a plugin execution works like this: "this is where I want to execute the plugin and here only".

However, it actually works more like this: "I'm defining this execution. This execution is to be done for the following phase, and these plugin goals under this configuration are to be executed then. Oh, and here's an ID for the execution, since you say you need it".

In other words: **plugin executions are not exclusive for a plugin, or even a plugin goal**.

**However**, as [rec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511197/rec) correctly points out, you can override the settings of a plugin execution set by a parent POM by specifying **your own execution with the same ID**. Once again, check the Effective POM to find those IDs. At the moment, for Maven 3, there are two "pre-defined" executions for the `resources` plugin, in the JAR packaging type : `default-resources`, and `default-testResources`.

Note that this is not something you should be normally doing for the `resources` plugin, as this can break your build.

---

**EDIT:** in your situation, it's clear that you have two parts of your project:

- a WAR that contains some applications,
- a JAR that deploys your WAR to some container.

Maven differs in from `make` (in my understanding) is that it decouples the build process of artifacts. In other words, you should create two projects: one with a `WAR` packaging, the other with the `JAR` packaging. The latter should copy the `WAR` package into its `JAR`. On top of that is what's called a [multi-module project](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation).

Specifically what you can do is:

1. Separate the project into two: the one building the `JAR` and the one building the `WAR`.
2. Create the multi-module project that specifies the other two as [modules](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation). The `JAR` project should be **after** the `WAR` project. You can set the multi-module project [as a parent](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) to the other two, it will let you to synchronize versions and other configuration.
3. In your `JAR` project, add a plugin goal execution that copies the `WAR` to your package. You can use the [`dependency:copy`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) goal for this, e.g.:

   ```
   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>copy-war</id>
       <phase>generate-resources</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>copy</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <artifactItems>
           <artifactItem>
             <groupId>[your-war-group-id]</groupId>
             <artifactId>[your-war-artifact-id]</artifactId>
             <version>${project.version}</version>
             <type>war</type>
             <overWrite>true</overWrite>
             <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
             <destFileName>install.war</destFileName>
           </artifactItem>
         </artifactItems>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   (an alternative is to specify the package as a dependency and [use the assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html))
4. Run the build for the multi-module project with the `install` target. You need `install` because it ensures that the latest version of the `WAR` project will find its way into your local m2 repository, for the `JAR` project to pick up.

You can skip the multi-module bit and just create two separate projects. However, in this case you will need to run the `WAR` project's `install` target before the `JAR` project's `package` manually whenever there's a change in the former.

Comment: You missed to mention the key point: if you know the ID, then you can redefine an execution under the same id, basically overriding the previous or default definition.

Comment: @rec : Arrgh, you're right. In my urge to downplay the importance of `id` in what I think the OP understood, I completely neglected that point, which is something the OP needs. I'll edit that into the answer, thanks.

Comment: So `id` has special meaning. I just place it because I saw this example on the web: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html .

Comment: @flyer : yes, although note that in the example you're defining a new execution, you're not overriding anything (at least nothing from the packaging configuration).

Comment: I think I filter Maven mechanism by GNU make experience. Maybe I should set some `dependencies` and not redefine `phase`?

Comment: @flyer : it's hard to guess. It is now apparent that there is some underlying problem you're trying to solve. Please **edit your question** to specify exactly **what are you trying to do** (**not** what you think is wrong), otherwise I'm afraid it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your `EDIT`. I think this is way to go. It looks I was fighting against the Maven with my approach. I made a multi module trial project and seems to be nice. I am using `-assembly-` from start... According to your snippet is it possible to make such dependency not from WAR file, but from my `checksum-maven-` created file? I tried to do that, but no luck.

Comment: @flyer : Well, the `copy` goal copies the given artifact from your Maven repository, so it has to be there in the first place. Beyond that, it's hard to tell exactly what the problem might be. I suggest for you to ask another, relevant, question if you get stuck.

Comment: I added my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/18788153/743027 . I used your apprach to copy file. Your `-dependency-` seems to be working fine. But if I setup `-dependency-` from `checksum-` it copies the plugin, not the file created by plugin.

Comment: @flyer : seen it already :). If someone doesn't get ahead of me and if I don't forget, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about 2 different goals: `copy-resources` and `resources`. For most packaging types the latter is bound to the `process-resources` phase. That's the one you are seeing in the log.
To have `copy-resources` being executed during the `test`-phase, also add

```
<goals>
  <goal>copy-resources</goal>
</goals>
```

Hence, you can read it [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) too

Comment: From my observation `maven-resources-plugin` is executed before my 'compile'. Can this be the case? Why do you refer to `resources`?

Comment: You have to understand the difference between a plugin and a goal: a plugin is a collections of goals, which belong to eachother. The `maven-resource-plugin` has 3 goals: `resources`, `testResources` and `copy-resources`. (and there's a `help` goal as well). You cannot bind a plugin to a phase, only a goal. The `resources` goal is bound the the `process-resources` phase, which is before the `compile` phase.

Comment: Yes! You read my mind, or? :) exactly I though the phase generates goal at some point in time (between other phases)...

Comment: for every packaging-type (jar, war, ear) a predefined set of goals are bound to certain phases. It is up to the developer to bind more goals to phases. To do this, add a plugin to the `plugins` section of the pom and define which goal should be executed. Now the important part: some goals have a default phase configured. If you like that phase, leave it like this. In all other cases specify the phase when this goal needs to be executed.