# Maven - add checksum accessible inside Java another approach

Tags: java, maven

Still trick with Maven. My target is the same:

Application which provides:

1. JAR form `maven-assembly-plugin`

   - internally stored checksum file generated by `checksum-maven-plugin` from WAR
2. WAR file from `maven-war-plugin`

After some refining I finished with 2 modules project. I see two options:

```
1. Option:
    parent
      - module 1 for WAR (+ checksum-maven-plugin)
      - module 2 for JAR (with dependancy)
2. Option:
    parent
      - module 1 for WAR
      - module 2 for JAR (with dependency to WAR + checksum-maven-plugin)
```

I chose option 1. My parent:

```
modules -> deploy-webapp
        -> deploy
plugin -> compiler
```

My module 1:

```
set parent -> ...
plugin -> maven-war-plugin -> execution -> compile -> war
plugin -> checksum-maven-plugin -> execution -> package -> files
```

My module 2:

```
set parent -> ...
plugin -> maven-assembly-plugin -> execution -> package -> single
```

The above generates 3 files which I am interested (works OK):

```
module 1 -> target/webapp.war
module 1 -> target/webapp.war.md5
module 2 -> target/deploy-jar-with-dependances.jar
```

PROBLEM:

I need checksum inside JAR file. If everything which is created is some artifact, is this checksum artifact too? If yes the `maven-dependency-plugin` should do the job. But if I am going for (inside module 2):

```
maven-dependency-plugin -> copy-artifact:package:copy-> net.ju-n.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin -> ${basedir}/src/main/resources
```

It copies the content of the plugin, not artifact which is created by plugin...

Answer (score 1):

I find thinking about where to place configuration requires the same decisions as thinking about code. So, for a given thing, the code that uses that thing should handle that thing.

In other words, you should go with Option 2 - the WAR does not care about the checksum, so why should it generate it?

Instead, you should calculate the checksum in the JAR project. The plugin has a nice [`files` goal for that](http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/files-mojo.html). Here's a minimal example that should work for you.

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>files</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <fileSets>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>PATH_TO_WAR</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>test.txt</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileSet>
                    </fileSets>
                    <individualFilesOutputDirectory>PATH_TO_WAR</individualFilesOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Note that this plugin execution should happen **after** you copy the WAR into your JAR project (so that the file exists), specifically:

- if they're in different phases, [it should happen in a later phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference),
- if they're in the same phase, it should be located **after the WAR copy execution definition in the POM**, since Maven runs *plugin goal executions*, that are bound to the same phase, in the sequence it encounters them in the POM.